# GWT MVP - retriving custom event parameters problem

Tags: gwt, mvp

I am developing a GWT application with presenter, dispatcher and Gin. 
I have a presenter which is retrieving an `ArrayList<JobPosting>`  from 
server and firing a `ManageJobsEvent`.

```
dispatcher.execute(new GetJobPostings(userId), new 
DisplayCallback<GetJobPostingsResult>(display) { 
                        @Override 
                        protected void handleFailure(Throwable e) { 
                                e.printStackTrace(); 
                                Window.alert(SERVER_ERROR); 
                        } 
                        @Override 
                        protected void handleSuccess(GetJobPostingsResult value) { 
                                eventBus.fireEvent(new ManageJobsEvent(value.getUserId(), 
value.getJobPostings())); 
                        } 
                });
```

I get the callback to  `onPlaceRequest(PlaceRequest request)`  of my 
another presenter 
but how do i get the `ArrayList<JobPostings>` set in the event.

Comment: Please reformat your code so that it's easier to read. Also, what are you trying to get your place request to do, request job postings and publish an event? Your code seems to do that just fine (at least from what I can tell)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly, but since you are passing the `ArrayList<JobPostings>` to the constructor of the `ManageJobsEvent`, why not just add a getter to retrieve it?